# Running an android binary on Ubuntu (libc.so: invalid ELF header)

Tags: java, android, c, linux, unix

I am trying to run a java application on spring boot running on ubuntu. My application has a dependency on a jar file that loads two binaries:

"libc++_shared.so" and "libsigx.so"

I extracted the jar file and so files from an aar file that is created as a dependency for android, but I would really like to use this on my server. I was able to write the java code I need without an issue after I added the jar file as dependency to my spring boot application.

However, when these binaries are loaded(e.g `System.loadLibrary("c++_shared")`) in Java, I got an exception saying that libc.so is not found. Apparently, I needed to install some other binaries, so I installed the necessary binaries to my docker container by using

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Now I have all the binaries needed(libc.so, libm.so etc), but now when I run my jar file I get invalid ELF header exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/packages/lib/libc++_shared.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so: invalid ELF header`

When I run the `readelf -h` command on so files:

The c++ so file has `OS/ABI: UNIX - System V` header, while libc.so has `OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU`. Looks like binaries are not compatible and I am trying to find to solve this.

Couple of questions that come to mind are:

- Is it possible to get these binaries to run in a compatible way with some commands? Maybe convert binary for system v to gnu somehow?
- Is it possible to find "libc++_shared.so" and "libsigx.so" created for `OS/ABI:                            UNIX - GNU`

I am open to any workaround to get these libraries running together. Thanks

Comment: The TL;DR Install Android Studio and run in the emulator?

Comment: Related: [Running Android NDK binary on Linux desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42638513/295004) Based on your prior question you seem to be trying to add in 'song recognition' without a proper third-party API. Companies like [Google](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-machine-learning-behind-hum-to.html) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/shazamkit/) maintain them (new songs get added, etc.) for their own proprietary products.

Comment: @CraigEstey This is for a spring boot application that will be used as server.